# OroPlatform: override back-end scss variables

Tags: symfony, orocrm, orocommerce

### Context

I am trying to override scss variables from the default Oro back-end theme.

I have already read the documentation about the way to override a theme : https://doc.oroinc.com/frontend/back-office/themes/

For example, this kind of css lines works : (to change default img login page)

```css
.login-page {
  background: url(../../../../images/login-screen.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50% #fff;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 280px;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

### Problem

Here is my `settings.yml` file :

```yaml
label: Custom Oro Theme
styles:
  css:
    inputs:
      - 'bundles/oroui/css/scss/oro/variables/main-menu.scss': 'bundles/baltimoreapp/themes/oro/css/scss/main-menu.scss'
      - bundles/baltimoreapp/themes/oro/css/scss/styles.scss
    output: css/oro/oro.css
```

Here is the line I changed in the `main-menu.scss`:

```
$menu-background-color: red !default;
```

As you can see on the previous file, I have tried to replace an oroui file by my own file as it is described in the Oro documentation : https://doc.oroinc.com/frontend/storefront/css/

This command works `symfony console oro:assets:install  --symlink` but I can't see my changes on my Oro dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know,the solution above works only for Frontend Store themes.
If you want to update styles at Management Console you have to override them by your custom styles.
As an example,you could see admin [demo theme](https://github.com/oroinc/platform/blob/master/src/Oro/Bundle/UIBundle/Resources/public/themes/demo/css/scss/desktop/main-menu/main.scss).